# Max size limit for LocalStorage/IndexedDb in Cordova App

Tags: cordova, local-storage, indexeddb

What is the max limit for html5 localstorage & IndexedDb storages in an cordova app ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the browser your Cordova App is running in. A look at the table taken from [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/quota-research/#toc-mobile) might help. The whole article might be of interest as well ;)

```html
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Chrome</th>
      <th>Android Browser</th>
      <th>Firefox</th>
      <th>Safari</th>
      <th>Safari</th>
      <th>iOS WebView</th>
      <th>iOS WebView</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>40</th>
      <th>4.3</th>
      <th>34</th>
      <th>6, 7</th>
      <th>8</th>
      <th>6, 7</th>
      <th>8</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Application Cache</td>
      <td>up to quota</td>
      <td>Unlimited?</td>
      <td>5<span class="mb">MB</span>, Unlimited</td>
      <td>300<span class="mb">MB</span>?</td>
      <td>300<span class="mb">MB</span>?</td>
      <td>100<span class="mb">MB</span>?</td>
      <td>100<span class="mb">MB</span>?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>FileSystem</td>
      <td>up to quota</td>
      <td class="empty"></td>
      <td class="empty"></td>
      <td class="empty"></td>
      <td class="empty"></td>
      <td class="empty"></td>
      <td class="empty"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>IndexedDB</td>
      <td>up to quota</td>
      <td class="empty"></td>
      <td>5<span class="mb">MB</span>, Unlimited</td>
      <td class="empty"></td>
      <td>up to quota?</td>
      <td class="empty"></td>
      <td>up to quota?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>WebSQL</td>
      <td>up to quota</td>
      <td>200<span class="mb">MB</span>~</td>
      <td class="empty"></td>
      <td>5<span class="mb">MB</span>, 10<span class="mb">MB</span>, 25<span class="mb">MB</span>, 50<span class="mb">MB</span></td>
      <td>5<span class="mb">MB</span>, 10<span class="mb">MB</span>, 25<span class="mb">MB</span>, 50<span class="mb">MB</span></td>
      <td>50<span class="mb">MB</span></td>
      <td>50<span class="mb">MB</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>LocalStorage</td>
      <td>10<span class="mb">MB</span></td>
      <td>2<span class="mb">MB</span></td>
      <td rowspan="2">10<span class="mb">MB</span></td>
      <td>5<span class="mb">MB</span></td>
      <td>5<span class="mb">MB</span></td>
      <td>5<span class="mb">MB</span></td>
      <td>5<span class="mb">MB</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>SessionStorage</td>
      <td>10<span class="mb">MB</span></td>
      <td>Unlimited</td>
      <td>5<span class="mb">MB</span></td>
      <td>Unlimited</td>
      <td>5<span class="mb">MB</span></td>
      <td>Unlimited</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```